# Unity3D Function quits working after scene change

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Alright so I have a 'Minigame' that is not working properly.
Basically, my ClickedStartButton() is only half working.
If I press play and hit start everything works perfectly.
However, if I change scenes, then go back to the main menu and hit play it stops working. Nothing happens at all. I don't understand what part of my code would cause this issue due to the scene being reloaded. I know ClickedStartButton() is being called, because isRolling = true; is called. However it seems as though that is the only thing being called from the function after a scene reload. Because instead of my coins being scrolled through nothing happens.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class chestScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float msToWait = 10800000.0f; // Wait time for Chest.
    private const float ROLL_OFFSET = 650.0f;
    public GameObject chestTimer;
    private Button chestButton;
    public Button startButton;
    private Text chestTimerTxt;
    public GameObject chestTimerBg;
    private ulong lastChestOpen;
    public GameObject newGift;

    public Text coinTxt;

    public Transform RollContainer;
    private Transform[] rolls;
    public GameObject rewardPanels;

    private int coinAmt;

    private bool isInitialized;

    private bool isRolling;
    private float transition;
    private string giftName;

    private int playerCoins;

    private void Start()
    {
        isRolling = false;
        InitializeGiftbox ();
    }
    private void InitializeGiftbox()
    {
        rewardPanels.SetActive (false);

        coinAmt = 0;

        chestButton = GetComponent<Button> ();
        lastChestOpen = ulong.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString ("LastChestOpen"));
        chestTimerTxt = GetComponentInChildren<Text> ();
        rewardPanels.SetActive (false);
        if (!IsChestReady ()) {
            startButton.interactable = false;
            chestButton.interactable = false;
            newGift.SetActive (false);
            chestTimerBg.SetActive (true);
            chestTimer.SetActive (true);
        }
        rolls = new Transform[RollContainer.childCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < RollContainer.childCount; i++)
            rolls [i] = RollContainer.GetChild (i);

        isInitialized = true;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!chestButton.IsInteractable ()) 
        {
            if (IsChestReady ()) {
                chestButton.interactable = true;
                startButton.interactable = true;
                chestTimer.SetActive (false);
                chestTimerBg.SetActive (false);
                newGift.SetActive (true);
                return;
            }
            //Set Timer in h:m:s format
            ulong diff = ((ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks - lastChestOpen);
            ulong m = diff / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
            float secondsLeft = (float)(msToWait - m) / 1000.0f;

            string r = " ";
            //Hours
            r += ((int)secondsLeft / 3600).ToString("00") + " : ";
            secondsLeft -= ((int)secondsLeft / 3600) * 3600;
            //Minutes
            r += ((int)secondsLeft / 60).ToString("00") + " : ";
            //Seconds
            r += ((int)secondsLeft % 60).ToString("00"); 
            chestTimerTxt.text = r;

        }
        if (isRolling) 
        {
            Vector3 end = (-Vector3.right * ROLL_OFFSET) * (rolls.Length - 1);
            RollContainer.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp (Vector3.right * ROLL_OFFSET, end, transition);
            transition += Time.deltaTime / 5.0f;
            if (transition > 1) 
            {
                isRolling = false;
                playerCoins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("coinAmount");
                chestButton.interactable = false;
                startButton.interactable = false;
                chestTimer.SetActive (true);
                chestTimerBg.SetActive (true);
                newGift.SetActive (false);
                switch (giftName) 
                {
                case "15Gold":
                    playerCoins += 15;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("coinAmount", playerCoins);
                    coinTxt.text = playerCoins.ToString();
                    break;
                case "5Gold":
                    playerCoins += 5;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("coinAmount", playerCoins);
                    coinTxt.text = playerCoins.ToString();
                    break;
                case "10Gold":
                    playerCoins += 10;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("coinAmount", playerCoins);
                    coinTxt.text = playerCoins.ToString();
                    break;
                case "1000Gold":
                    playerCoins += 1000;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("coinAmount", playerCoins);
                    coinTxt.text = playerCoins.ToString();
                    break;
                case "100Gold":
                    playerCoins += 100;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("coinAmount", playerCoins);
                    coinTxt.text = playerCoins.ToString();
                    break;
                case "40Gold":
                    playerCoins += 40;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("coinAmount", playerCoins);
                    coinTxt.text = playerCoins.ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                case "Nothing":
                    Debug.Log ("Nothing happened");
                    break;
                }
                PlayerPrefs.Save ();
            }
        }
    }
    public void ChestClick()
    {       
        rewardPanels.SetActive (true);
    }
    private bool IsChestReady()
    {
        ulong diff = ((ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks - lastChestOpen);
        ulong m = diff / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        float secondsLeft = (float)(msToWait - m) / 1000.0f;

        if (secondsLeft < 0) {
            startButton.interactable = true;
            chestButton.interactable = true;
            chestTimer.SetActive (false);
            chestTimer.SetActive (false);
            newGift.SetActive (true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void ClickedStartButton()
    {
        lastChestOpen = (ulong)DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString ("LastChestOpen", lastChestOpen.ToString ());
        transition = 0;
        float offset = 0.0f;
        List<int> indexes = new List<int> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < rolls.Length; i++)
            indexes.Add (i);

        for (int i = 0; i < rolls.Length; i++) {
            int index = indexes [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, indexes.Count)];
            indexes.Remove (index);
            rolls [index].transform.localPosition = Vector3.right * offset;
            offset += ROLL_OFFSET;
            giftName = rolls [index].name;
        }
        isRolling = true;
    }
    public void ClickedCloseButton()
    {
        rewardPanels.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`DontDestroyOnLoad(Object)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure why, but for some reason Timescale is transferred over between scenes in Unity so by adding

```
Time.timeScale = 1;
```

It fixed my issue, hopefully this will help others who's buttons quit working upon scene changes. Simple fix.

Comment: Well of course it "transfers between scenes." It's a *global value.*